# 'nvm' is not recognized && npm install

Tags: javascript, npm-install, nvm-windows

I got home exam and I have 2 problems. (Windows)

1. When I run `nvm use 12.7` in Powershell, I get this message:

```
nvm : The term 'nvm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nvm use 12.7
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nvm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

2. When I run `npm install`:

```
lerna ERR! npm install exited 1 in '@ans-exam/client' 
npm ERR! answers-entry-level-exam@1.0.0 bootstrap: `lerna bootstrap`
```

I have installed nvm, npm and node.

Comment: is NVM added to the environment variables of the system,. Similar error is shown in such cases.

Comment: yeah, apart from the above suggestion, we need to refresh bash / re-open command line terminal.